# TinyMCE plugin - image

Tags: nuxt.js, tinymce-5

I'm using TinyMCE in a Nuxt project, but I'm having trouble with certain plugins. For instance, the 'image' plugin isn't functioning as expected - when I click on the icon, the window to insert the URL doesn't open, and it ends up freezing my page. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it?

This is the part of the code where I'm inputting the data, and some plugins like 'lists' work perfectly fine.

```
        api-key="-----"
        :init="{
          height: 300,
          menubar: false,
          // icons: 'bootstrap',
          skin: useDarkMode ? 'oxide-dark' : 'oxide',
          content_css: useDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'default',
          plugins: 
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap ' +
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen ' +
            'preview anchor insertdatetime media ' +
            'code help wordcount table',
          toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline | bullist numlist hr | help | image',
          }"
```